# Why does the C "long" data type compile to two MSP430 ".word"s?

Tags: c, assembly, msp430

[image]

I understand that:

```
char (1 byte)
short (2 bytes)
long (4 bytes)
long long (8 bytes)
```

But when converting C to assembly  why is there an extra `.word 0` or `.word -1`?

Comment: Two 16-bit `.word` values to create a single 32-bit  [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) value (in "little endian" [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness))?

Comment: Are you wondering why there are two (consider the size of a word) or wondering why they have the values they have?

Comment: The short answer is that because msp430 is a 16-bit platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of a C variable type is specific to the authors choices for that compiler and target.  There is no fixed rule by definition.  For one (version of) a compiler an int can be 16 bits for one target and 32 for another.  For two different compilers same target one can choose 16 bits another 32.  And sizes don't have to line up with the general purpose register sizes - author's choice.

This is what stdint.h is all about, it is part of the compiler ultimately and connects the dots between 8, 16, 32, 64, etc sizes and the chosen sizes for the compiler for that target, a specific version of gcc for x86's stdint.h is not expected to be compatible for the same version of gccs msp430 stdint.h for example.

What appears to be going on here is as you described.

```
char (1 byte)
short (2 bytes)
long (4 bytes)
long long (8 bytes)
```

Assembly language is specific to the assembler, the tool, not the target, the author of the assembler can choose whatever syntax and mnemonics, etc, they choose.  Being somewhat related to the chip documentation is the sane path, but there is certainly no rules for assembly language.  In particular how you define data items.  It appears here that .word means a 16 bit value here and .byte an 8 bit value.

```
2048 = 0x0000....00800
-2048 = 0xFFFF....FF800
```

so if you clip off the lower 8 bits of 2048 you get 0x00, you chop off the lower 16 you get 0x0800, the lower 32 you get 0x00000800, so

```
.byte 0x00

.word 0x0800
```

assuming little endian:

```
.word 0x0800
.word 0x0000
```

for 8, 16, and 32 bits

In decimal:

```
.byte 0

.word 2048

.word 2048
.word 0
```

or

```
.word 2048,0
```

depending on the assembler's syntax

for the negative version -2048

```
.byte 0x00

.word 0xF800

.word 0xF800
.word 0xFFFF
```

for 8, 16, and 32 bit versions of that number

in decimal

```
.byte 0

.word -2048

.word -2048
.word -1
```

and a long long -2048 would be

```
.word -2048
.word -1
.word -1
.word -1
```

or long long -2048 could also be implemented as:

```
.byte 0
.byte -8
.byte -1
.byte -1
.byte -1
.byte -1
.byte -1
.byte -1
```

both generating the exact same data in the binary.

Comment: I am of course assuming the assembler recognizes hex as 0x1234 instead of $1234 or 1234h or other if it supports hex values at all.

Comment: Assuming this is GCC output, it's GAS syntax, so yes that's a good assumption; GAS uses `0x1234` for hex constants, and doesn't recognize those other ways.

Comment: As you know I am trying to make a generic point about assembly languages, the syntax does imply gas, yes, which implies the C style hex syntax.  The OP did not provide enough information in the question for a definitive answer.

Comment: Various types must be able to represent a *minimum* range of values - an `int` must able to represent values in *at least* the range `[-32767..32767]`, meaning it must be *at least* 16 bits wide.  It may be wider, it may have padding bits, but it must contain *at least* 16 value bits.  Implementors do have a lot of leeway in how to map those requirements onto the hardware, but it's not a total free-for-all.

Comment: fair enough, thank you for the clarification I was going more for the its not rigid, but not being as flexible as I claimed is also good information.

Comment: I would also hope a short is bigger than or equal to a byte and int bigger than or equal to short and so on...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but I think your problem is that you know about assembler on other CPUs (for example x86) and you assume that `.word` is a 32-bit word.

However, both assembler statements like `.word` and `.long` and C data types (!) are processor specific and even operating system specific.

Examples: `long` means 4 bytes on x86-64 Windows and 8 bytes on x86-64 Linux; `char` means one byte on x86 and two bytes on MSP320F28x.

On an MSP430, the statement `.word` obviously means 16 bits while the statement `.long` seems not to exist in the assembler you are using.

Because the C data type `long` is 32 bits on the MSP430, two `.word` statements (2x16 bits) are required for one variable of the type `long`.

Answer (score 2):

MSP430 is a 16 bit CPU so it has no hardware support for 32 bit numbers. Like any such low-end MCU it will therefore have to rely on software libs to handle larger types - the compiler will inline functions for this in your code soon as you use 32 bit arithmetic. And this is the very reason why 32 bit arithmetic is inefficient on 16 bitters and *terribly* inefficient on 8 bitters.

The term "word" is rather broad but generally refers to the largest chunk of data that the CPU can store in a data register and process in a single instruction. This "word size" is what makes your MSP430 "16 bit". In the C language, a "word" corresponds to the type `int`, which will therefore be 16 bits on this system.

It is very important to know the size and range of `int` when programming in C, because that one affects the type of integer constants `123`, the type used for implicit promotion of small integer types and so on.

Though when programming embedded systems you should never use any of these types explicitly, you should be using the types from `stdint.h`.